# CakePHP using multiple databases for models

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

Is it possible for certain models to be in one database and other models in another (using the same connection)?

I have a number of read-only tables that I want shared between multiple installations of my system. Other tables need to be per-installation. For the sake of example, let's say `users` is the shared table, and `posts` is per-installation.

In one schema (let's call it "shared") we have the `users` table, and in another schema ("mycake") is `posts`.

I've been able to get the User model reading from the other database by creating a new database connection which points to the shared database (though the two databases are on the same host and are both accessible with the same login details).

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $useDBConfig = 'sharedConnection';
}
```

The problem is when it comes time to join to the `posts` table. It doesn't prepend the schema name to the table name, and so it can't find `posts`.

```
// what it does
SELECT * FROM users User INNER JOIN posts Post ...

// what I'd like it to do:
SELECT * FROM shared.users User INNER JOIN mycake.posts Post ...
```

So basically, **is there a way to assign a fully qualified table name to a model and force it to use that in all its queries?** Setting `var $useTable = 'shared.users';` doesn't help...

Comment: This is a good question. When choosing a framework (in PHP), I always check if the framework will allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2007/06/04/multiple-dbs-in-cakephp/) has a way to do it, but it's a little hacky.

Comment: heh - "little" is a bit of an understatement. I'll give it a shot anyway.

Comment: It's a bit outdated, but I was able to hack it together to get it working.

Comment: The article is now at: http://recursive-design.com/blog/2007/06/04/multiple-dbs-in-cakephp/

Answer (score 1):

I've built a site in CakePHP that has models using different databases and I never had problem with joins across different databases - the framework seemed to take care of all that for me. Though you might need to explicitly state the database tables used in your models to get it to work.

Comment: I just used different login details for each database. From memory when they shared the login there were problems.

Answer (score 0):

To switch the database for the model,

Use the namespace in the controller/model

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
```

In controller;-

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('remote_db_1');
$this->ModelName->connection($conn);
```

In model:-

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('remote_db_1');
$this->connection($conn);
```

> Note:- If you are saving data for the associated tables too, then keep
>   in mind to change the DB for the associated data otherwise data for
>   the associated table will be inserted into the default connection/DB.

This is the answer for CakePHP 3.*