# how to connect two DB in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I have working on a project which contains two DB , the common tables are in main DB and some specific tables are in separate DB.

I need to connect the DB dynamically because the second DB is based on the user they log-in in site . We get the details from DB and then create a DB settings and connect .

Can anyone help on this concept.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788072/cakephp-using-multiple-databases-for-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used this method

```
function dbConnect($config = array()) {
    $config['datasource'] = 'test';
    ClassRegistry::init('ConnectionManager');
    // echo "<pre>";print_R($config);die;
    // echo $nds = $config['datasource'] . '_' . $config['dbname'];
    $nds = $config['datasource'] . '_' . $config['dbname'];
    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($config['datasource']);
    $dbprfx = $config['dbname'].'_';
    $db->setConfig(array('name' => $nds, 'database' => $config['dbname'],'prefix' => $dbprfx, 'persistent' => false));
    if($ds = ConnectionManager::create($nds, $db->config)) return $db->config;
    return false;

}
```

which works fine

thanks for all replies.